# Hue does not color according to a given column when using seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, plot, seaborn

I am trying to draw a joint plot for three variables. But I want my datapoints to be coloured by a specific column ('class'). However, it is not doing so. This is what I get:

[image]

The code I use to produce is:

```
data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,8,9,10], 
        'y': [2, 4, 1.5, 4, 3, 5,3,5,2], 
        'class': ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0','2','2','2']}
sns.jointplot(data=data, x='x', y='y', hue='class', kind='kde',
              fill=True, joint_kws={'alpha': 0.7})
```

Can someone tell me how can I color my plot according to column 'class' like they do in documentation:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html

EDIT:

Plot of real data:

[image]

But my dataframe for both true column and prediction column the values range between 0 and 1 and here it is going between -0.2 to 1.2. Why do you think that is.

Comment: You need to update your seaborn.

Comment: Thanks. It worked but when I plotted my real dataset it was messing up the axis. Values for both prediction and true range between 0 and 1 whereas with my plot I get negative values. Why is that?

Comment: Read the "notes" section here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html